# Whats best way to track changes of software installation and post-configuration?

Tags: linux, audit

I'm trying to track all files installed and modified by .bin package (I'm on RHEL 5.5), also it would be nice to track changes made in the configuration files by post-installation wizard.
Any suggestions how can I do this?
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/3852/what-tool-do-you-recommend-to-track-changes-on-a-linux-unix-server

Comment: thanks for reply, I had a look at etckeeper, I could not make it monitor other directory rather than /etc, preferably with recursive option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely overkill, but using subversion or some similar version control software would show you what files have been changed. Tripwire would work well too. You could also just md5sum the files and diff them, etc.